# Trouble on using the i18n gem with "resources of resources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to know how to correctly handle internationalization related to "resources of resources". That is, ...

... in my `config/routes.rb` file I have:

```
resources :users do
  resource :account
end
```

... in my `app/models/users/account.rb` file I have:

```
class Users::Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :firstname,
    :presence => true
  ...
end
```

... in my `config/locales/models/user/account/en.yml` file I have:

```
en:

  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        presence: "custom presence message - english"
```

... in my `config/locales/models/user/account/it.yml` file I have:

```
it:

  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        presence: "custom presence message - italian"
```

*The above code doesn't display in front end the "`custom presence message`"* (it still displays the default RoR presence message: `can not be blank`). Furthermore if in my `app/models/users/account.rb` file I use:

```
class Users::Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :firstname,
    :presence => { :message => t(:presence) } # Here I try to use the i18n helper method
  ...
end
```

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `t' for #<Class:0x000001075bbc80>)
```

**Why I get the `NoMethodError`?**

**Is the problem related to how I am organizing in directories my locale files?** At this time (as stated in the [official RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#organization-of-locale-files)) my file system is:

```
config/locales/defaults/en.yml
config/locales/defaults/it.yml
config/locales/models/user/en.yml
config/locales/models/user/it.yml
config/locales/models/user/account/en.yml
config/locales/models/user/account/it.yml
```

*In few words, I would like to display my "`custom presence message`" only on validating "resources of resources" kind of `Users::Account`.* **How can I do that?**

---

I also tried to state the following code in the `config/locales/models/user/account/en.yml` file

```
en:

  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          account:
            attributes:
              firstname:
                blank: "custom presence message - english"
```

but it doesn't work. Anyway the following works but *I need different translations for different attributes* (as I tried to state in the previous code example):

```
en:

  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        blank: "custom presence message - english"
```

Comment: 5.1.1 Error Message Scopes - please read that section carefully of very same guide you mentioned

Comment: @Piotr Mąsior - I read that section (it also mentions models inheritance that, in my case, I am not using), but I can not find information about "resources of resources" and how to organize related locale files. Furthermore I do not know why I get the `NoMethodError`.

Comment: If you go to ActiveModel gem lib/active_model/errors.rb line 297 inside "generate_message" definition you will find out that there is something like class.model_name.i18n_key invoked.... and it generates for namespaced models something like: => :"users/account"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, due to this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1402 last comment nested model look-up is removed

so try maybe something like

```
activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        users:
          account:
            attributes:
              first_name:
                blank: "You should fill up first name field to complete that"
```

and change inside :message hash to

```
I18n.t(:"activerecord.errors.models.users.account.attributes.first_name.blank")
```

and try avoid nested models ;-)

update:

after some debuging this will work:

```
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        "users/account":
            attributes:
              first_name:
                blank: "You should fill up first name field to complete that"
```